# How to set the language of the address in Google Maps for Android?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am using *GeoCoder* to fetch a user address by GPS coordinates from *Google Maps*, but it returns the address in English.

How can I display the address in the current country's language, for example Persian?

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale iran = new Locale("fa");
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), iran);
```